# How do I access Java code from my Groovy scripts in a convenient manner?

Tags: java, groovy, classpath, integration

I work on a decent sized Java project which uses Perl scripts for some glue code. I'm trying to figure out how to replace these with Groovy scripts so that we have the convenience of scripting, but better access to all that Java code that has been built up over the years. Here's an example of what our project structure looks like.

```
.
|____core
| |____classes
| | |____com
| |   |____project
| |     |____core
| |       |____CoreClass.class
| |____src
|   |____com
|     |____project
|       |____core
|         |____CoreClass.java
|____scripts
| |____someScript.groovy
|____util
  |____classes
  | |____com
  |   |____project
  |     |____util
  |       |____UtilClass.class
  |____src
    |____com
      |____project
        |____util
          |____UtilClass.java
```

(Note: `util` and `core` are just two of about a dozen similar folders in the project)

I would like to run `someScript.groovy` from the command line, and it needs to be able to instantiate both `UtilClass` and `CoreClass`. I've read various ways to set up the classpath with Groovy scripts, but none that I have found are suitable.

The point here is to find a way to use Groovy that is easier to use than our current system using Perl. In order to do this, I think I need to meet three criteria.

- No pollution of the system or environment

I want to keep the project as self contained as possible. A developer should be able to check the project out of source control, run `someScript.groovy` and have it know where to find the other classes in the project. I don't want to require a developer to set the CLASSPATH environment variable to point to all the project class directories.

- No long command line parameters

The scripts should be easy to run from the command line. If the `-cp` flag were required, the developer would have to type a novel in order to specify all the various class directories in our project.

- No boilerplate in `someScript.groovy`

I've seen some solutions involving getting an instance of the class loader and specifying paths to `.java` or `.class` files. This will make scripts too hard and tedious to write.

These criteria are not absolute. If I have to budge on one of them a little bit, the solution may still work. We use Eclipse here, so a solution involving some type of project configuration via Eclipse might be suitable. If boilerplate code is needed, perhaps having a Groovy source file that gets automatically compiled by Eclipse to a version containing the necessary boilerplate code.

Calling the script via either `groovy someScript.groovy` or `someScript.groovy` would probably be acceptable.

Comment: It sounds as if you want the Stack Overflow community to create an architecture for you from scratch. I'm not sure that's fair. What is your question, exactly?  Have you tried [asking the duck?](http://hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html)

Comment: I don't want anyone to create anything for me. I mainly need a nudge in the right direction from someone who knows the Java ecosystem better than I do. I can build anything that needs to be built myself.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write a shell script that accepts the name of the Groovy script to be run. The shell script then calls the `groovy` command, passing along the Groovy script and the correct (relative) class path.

Since the Groovy Eclipse plugin can run Groovy scripts, another options might be to fiddle with run configurations and set the correct class path there.

Answer (score 0):

why not include groovy-all.jar and other dependencies in the "lib/" directory.  Then write wrapper .bat and .sh scripts which set the classpath to "lib/*".   There's a main class "groovy.lang.GroovyShell" which you can pass the script to run as an argument.

### somescript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp 'lib/*' groovy.lang.GroovyShell somescript.groovy
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an one alternative:

1. Download the latest groovy release
2. Copy the `bin/, conf/ and lib/` directories from groovy to your project root
3. Edit `conf/groovy-starter.conf`

add the following entries

```
load !{groovy.home}/core/classes
load !{groovy.home}/util/classes
....and all your other directories
```

To run `someScript.groovy` you would run the following command from the project root:

```
bin/groovy scripts/someScript.groovy
```

This is fully self contained and the developer does not need groovy installed.  All that is required is `JAVA_HOME` set.  Whenever you want to upgrade groovy, just download the latest release and replace the `bin/` and `lib/` directories.

If `lib/` is already a directory in your project you can rename the groovy lib to `groovy-lib/` and just adjust the entry in the `conf/groovy-starter.conf` (and you may also have to adjust a line or two in the `bin/startGroovy` script).

You can always create a wrapper script in your project root that calls `bin/groovy scripts/someScript.grooy` if you want to simplify things further.

Comment: This looks like the best answer so far. I will poke at this and see how far I get.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add things to the root classloader of your Groovy script by using:

```
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new URL('file:///path/to/jar'))
```

So all that's left is for the script to determine where the script itself is:

```
scriptDir = new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).parent
```

Then find all the jars in that tree.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use derived loader, when I can accept only for example classes from ok / forbidden packages (i.e. no files from io package etc)

```
package script;

import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationFailedException;

import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader;

public class MyGroovyClassLoader extends GroovyClassLoader {

@Override
public Class loadClass(String name, boolean lookupScriptFiles, boolean preferClassOverScript) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        CompilationFailedException {
    if( ... ! requiredPackaIsOk ... ) 
        throw Exception("class cannot be loaded"); 
    return super.loadClass(name, lookupScriptFiles, preferClassOverScript);
}

@Override
public Class loadClass(String name, boolean lookupScriptFiles, boolean preferClassOverScript, boolean resolve)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, CompilationFailedException {
    if( ... ! requiredPackaIsOk ... ) 
        throw Exception("class cannot be loaded"); 
        return super.loadClass(name, lookupScriptFiles, preferClassOverScript, resolve);
}

@Override
protected Class loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if( ... ! requiredPackaIsOk ... ) 
        throw Exception("class cannot be loaded"); 
        return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
}
```

}